# GridView with fixed height and variable widths for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm looking for the exact solution used by the stock Photo app in Windows 10 to display a list of photos where the dimensions are different. Basically the height of the row are fixed but the width of each element is variable, determined by its relative dimension. A solution I used before was to use WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate. But using that means I lose the UI virtualisation for a very long list. There is certainly a solution used by Microsoft for the Photo app but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WrapPanel from [XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) in your UWP application.

Or you can try to do it this way:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}"> 
<GridView.ItemTemplate> 
<DataTemplate> 
<Grid Width="100">
<Image Width="100" Height="50" Source="{Binding somesource}" /> 
</Grid> 
</DataTemplate> 
</GridView.ItemTemplate> 
<GridView.ItemsPanel> 
<ItemsPanelTemplate> 
<ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="8" Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate> 
</GridView.ItemsPanel> 
</GridView>
```

Or you can also use [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid.aspx) (it will let you to have images with different height)

Comment: I tried your suggestion with ItemsWrapGrid. It behaves like default GridView. And unfortunately WrapPanel and VariableSizedWrapGrid doesn't support virtualization as stated in [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview). There must be a solution used by Microsoft for their Photo app and I am still searching.

Comment: In UWP you can try make incremental loading with attribute x:Phase and compiled bindings x:Bind